# Json-data is empty without any error when inserted in database from psycopg2 and python3

Tags: json, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the problem with inserting data to the ONE column of the table in the database.

I use psycopg2 and python3.6 to try to insert data to the table. The data for inserting has some params of different types: str, int, json etc.

My query is:

```
UPDATE i_proc 
SET ad_info = '{"codes": ["P12", "P14"], "score": 3, "score2": 0}',
    result_code_id = 33,
    status = 'wait'
WHERE id=122;
```

If I do it from the graphical database management tool (dbeaver) all is OK: all values correctly insert up into columns. Without any errors or somthing else.

But if I do it from python:

```
from psycopg2._json import Json

ad_info = Json(additional_info)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    ("UPDATE i_proc SET status = '{status}', result_code_id =33, \
                ad_info = {ad_info} \
            WHERE id = {id};"
         ).format(
            status=status,
            id=id,
            ad_info=ad_info
        ))

cursor.close()
conn.commit()
```

Then all of values will be inserted into the table EXCEPT ad_info! Without errors etc. This row will has **status** is 'wait' and **id** is 33, but **ad_info** will be ***empty***.

To run from dbeaver I use the same SQL-query that was taken from log of python code running. Therefore it is the identical query.

As well, I has another part of code in other part of project where I use bjson-data and in that part identical code works fine, bjson-data correctly inserted.

Whats wrong here? Any help, please.

Comment: If you want to update this way, just use `json.dumps(additional_info)`, no need to use Json from psycopg2. Also it should be `'{ad_info}'` in query. And `commit` should go before closing the cursor.

Comment: Thank you. This variant is working. Now I'm interested in why in another part of my project my first variant works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, ildus.

> use json.dumps(additional_info), no need to use Json from psycopg2. Also it should be '{ad_info}' in query.

It works

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what value in `additional_info` but 
I supposed to that `ad_info = {ad_info}` is incorrect. It should be like `ad_info = '{ad_info}'` because you provide json as string to db.

Comment: Sorry, it's incorrect answer. 1. add_info is json, this is in my question. 2. It's bad idea to convert bjson to str to insert into json-type column. It will not work and It's not working. 3. I described the other part of my project that is identical of this part and in that place only value_name = {value} for json object and json-column.